# Soft keyboard changes when app is unlocked

Tags: flutter, android-softkeyboard

I am having a problem with soft keyboard in flutter. My keyboard input type is number. whenever i open the soft keyboard, lock phone and then unlock phone, the number type keyboard changes to alpha numeric though i cannot type in the text field.
Could somebody please help me?

https://repo.ekbana.info/codefirm/raven/raven-pm/uploads/a31f5a5f66c27507aa521eadd0cd46c2/screen-20221219-165145.mp4

Comment: Can you share your input field code? Then I can try to find out the actual problem, I'm not sure. I guess why it didn't work after re-open. You did

        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
          ],

Comment: yes sir i did
   keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,

 inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],

Comment: full code is 
TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        phoneNumberValidityFlag =
                            isPhoneNumberValid(phoneController.text);
                      });
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    controller: phoneController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],
                  )

Comment: I can't think more about it because the keyboard is dismissed when it closed. Can you try to Set the autofocus = true on your TextField to get the focus when the page is loaded and use FocusNode? do some research with FocusNode and lemme know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
@override Future didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async { if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) { FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); } super.didChangeDependencies(); }
```

The `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method is called whenever the state of the application's lifecycle changes. In your case, you are checking if the state parameter is equal to AppLifecycleState.resumed, which means that the application has come back to the foreground after being in the background.

When the application resumes, you are calling `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` to unfocus any active focus nodes in the current context. This should prevent the keypad from changing to the text input mode when the phone is locked and unlocked.